# Does this qualify as a one-way function?

Tags: collision-resistance, one-way-function, preimage-resistance

First, we observe that the expression X*Y mod P (where X and Y are secret and P is a large public prime) [reveals no useful information](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/26079/how-is-information-disclosed-by-modular-multiplication).

Next we define an extending function E(U, M) which "somehow" transforms U in such a way to guarantee that the result consists of at least M bits. For example, by returning the bit pattern of U with the Mth bit set. (In practice we might add a few more constraints there in order to satisfy non-malleability).

Finally, we have a function F defined as follows:

Q = E(V, N)

F = (Q * E((Q * A) mod B, N)) mod C

Where A, B, C are large public primes, V is secret, and N is the number of bits of the largest prime.

So my question is, does F satisfy all of the following properties: non-reversibility, preimage resistance, and collision resistance?

Comment: Does the problem statement mention that $E$ is [injective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injective_function)? Otherwise, what about $E(U,m)$ ignoring $U$ and returning the $m$-bit bitstring with $m$ bits at $1$? The corresponding $F$ would collide a lot. Also, $E$ must probably be independent of $A$, $B$ and $C$.

Comment: Yes, which is precisely what I was referring to when I mentioned additional constraints. The actual idea I had in mind was to repeatedly concatenate the input with itself (separated by a restricted "symbol") at least once in order to ensure that E(U, m) is unique for all U. Furthermore, the computation of E does not involve any of A, B, or C.

Comment: It's difficult for anyone to answer your questions as the function F relies heavily on the largely unspecified function E.  If E is SHA512 then F seems a lot better than if E is simply <<7.  But if E is oracle-like then it suggests F need not exist.  Note that if Q=E(v1,N)==Q=(E,v2,N) then it follows that Q*E(Q*A mod B,N) will be the same and this step is t/f unnecessary.  In real life, use proper crypto. For fun, maybe look into NH-hashing into a large array of say 1024 64 bit hashes, then sieving them down into 8 or 4 using XOR/mod addition.  I've already coded this if you are interested.

Comment: Sure, I'd love to see it. And most likely I'll be posting a link to my final implementation as well once all of the details are ironed out. Anyway, the extension function as elaborated is not oracle-like, but is injective, which should be sufficient here.

Comment: And just a comment, I would argue that nailing down properties and requirements is in fact "real crypto". Just consider the fact that many of the algorithms currently in use carry such a moniker and yet are nonetheless difficult to analyze and thus not necessarily provably secure. So if one could systematically identify simple primitives which are, then perhaps we're actually making a bit of progress. No?

Comment: We have these simple primitives - they are, for example, confusion and diffusion.

Comment: Well just look at the description of SHA-2 for example. Can we really say that it's "provably secure"? It difficult to say, and so there is a non-negligible chance that (much like algorithms like SHA-1/MD5/etc) it too will one day be broken, considering it's overwhelming complexity.

Comment: Could you clarify what F is a function of? Is it F(V)?

Comment: Sure, there is no reduction to a presumably hard problem. However SHA-1 wasn't broken by some cryotoanalytic breakthrough, its state was just too small.

Comment: Yes, exactly. F(V) = (E(V, N) * E((E(V, N) * A) mod B, N)) mod C.

Comment: WRT to whether or not SHA-1 was actually broken, just consider this quote from Wikipedia: "Due to the block and iterative structure of the algorithms and the absence of additional final steps, all SHA functions (except SHA-3[26]) are vulnerable to length-extension and partial-message collision attacks." So not merely an issue of the size of its state, and moreover notice that this problem also applies to SHA-2!

Comment: What you're talking about is merely a consequence of using a Merkle Damgard construction, these are not issues with the underlying compression function. And we can prove that you require collisions for the compression function, to find a collision of the entire hash function. Additionally, length extension attacks can be avoided by simply truncating the output - essentially what SHA2-384 does.

Comment: I retract my earlier statement that SHA1 wasn't broken by crypto analysis. It seems there were at least some issues with the compression function, that allowed a faster than brute-force search.

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/strdnl/KDF/blob/main/main.js) is the code to the aforementioned hash function.  It builds a large 512kb array of 64bit hashes from a 8*32 bit input then sieves them down to a 512bit hash.  Regarding "real crypto" I just meant using stuff that was built/tested by real cryptographers for real-life applications.  Fair enough if it is for fun or assignment.

Comment: Well, to that let me just say this. My great-great-great grandfather was a renowned surgeon way back when. Now did he accomplish such a thing by spending years at school? No. He had absolutely no formal training whatsoever. Just a copy of Grey's Anatomy and a strong will to heal others. The point is we often mistake a person's experience as a proper measure of their ability to solve certain problems. And yet in life we often find just the opposite to be true. People with lot's of training and credentials who nonetheless make critical mistakes in the exercise of their craft, for example.

Comment: So judging whether or not someone is capable of achieving some goal is sometimes less a matter of how "qualified" they are so much as it is a question of how resourceful they are at identifying the problem space, asking the right questions, and iteratively addressing issues as they arise. I understand that not everyone is going to agree with that statement, but that's my two cents anyhow.

Comment: @ModalNest Your KDF implementation looks interesting. Can you provide more info on the mechanics of how it actually works?

Comment: I presume you don't mean how the example code works, which is essentially just kdf(key).  I've written a short [readme](https://github.com/strdnl/KDF/) and also amended the code slightly (the build function) as the modulus was wrong and every round was the same.

Comment: @ModalNest Thanks! Still a bit unsure how it actually works, but I'll spend some more time on it over the next few days till it sinks in. I did finally finish putting together a basic proof of concept on this one as well (link is posted above in original question). Cheers!

Comment: Thank you for your link.  I will have a look and do some basic tests today.  I've updated code my code again as the modulus was stupid meaning 1 bit of the last 4 parts of the  key could be flipped.  It now passes my non-rigorous bit flipping tests.  I've updated the readme too (hopefully it's a little clearer).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116367/discussion-between-modal-nest-and-sir-galahad).

Comment: @ModalNest Sure thing. Got a little busy today but finally have some free time to take another look at it.

Comment: Voted to close, because the real question "analyze my design" is considered off-topic here. Additionally, this is a QA sure. Not a discussion site. Regarding the design: Complexity for complexity sake is bad. Complexity that makes the attackers work more difficult is good. The difference is all that matters. And this question does not indicate anything to the latter.

Comment: @tylo There was a lot of confusion over the exact properties of E(U, M) which I think led to all the superfluous discussion. The question has been sufficiently answered anyway. X*Y mod P will not to leak information provided X and Y are truly independent. And finite abelian groups do indeed provide an acceptable mechanism for mapping X on to Y in such a way that this requirement is in fact preserved. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: For the sake of staying on-topic, I've removed implementation links.

Comment: @SirGalahad If you have an answer then please ask the person that led you in the right direction to write an answer or write one yourself. Or, if you think it is not useful to anybody else, then delete the question.